# How to use POST request in PHP with FullContactAPI for Batch Requests?

Tags: php, post, fullcontact

I am not able to request for data in batch from fullcontact API. The response received is "invalid query object" using the following code:

```
$urltopost = "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/batch.json?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxx";
$datatopost = array (
    "requests" => '["https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=bart@fullcontact.com","htps://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=jigarbhatt30893@yahoo.co.in"]'
);
$header=array("content-type"=>"application/json");
$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r($returndata);
```

Writing the shell execution which worked correctly.

```
curl --request POST "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/batch.json?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxx" --data '{'requests':["https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=bart@fullcontact.com","https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=jigarbhatt30893@yahoo.co.in"]}' --header 'content-type:application/json'
```

But I don't want to call shell_exec from php to do this. I want cURL functions to work. What's going wrong?

Comment: Thanks Danny for the edit help. I am seriously stuck on this problem for a while.

Comment: Here is the link where an example of Post request is provided. http://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/batch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So I think I found my own answer. I just had to change that array into string. And it worked perfectly.

```
$datatopost = '{"requests":["https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=bart@fullcontact.com","https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=jigarbhatt30893@yahoo.co.in"]}';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i have tested it and worked fine. No need to send data in post method

```
$urltopost = "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxx&email=someone@xyz.com&method=email";

$header=array("content-type"=>"application/json");
$ch = curl_init ($urltopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$returndata = curl_exec ($ch);
print_r($returndata);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try removing the single quotes from the request array.

```
"requests" => ["https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=bart@fullcontact.com","htps://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=jigarbhatt30893@yahoo.co.in"]
```